Internal energy of real gas
I saw an equation stating the expression of internal energy of real gas as
dU = CvdT + (T(dP/dT)v - P)dV
I want to know if this equation is true for every real gas equation or only for Van der waals gas equation. What would have if the real gas has something else for an equation like ideal gas equation but with a little fluctuation terms for example PV exp(a/RTV) = nRT.
Will the above expression of internal energy still be valid?
I would also like to know that whether the above equation can be used for obtaining expression involving only T and V in a scenario where a real gas initially with some V and T later expands to 2V and some temperature Tf.

It applies to all real gases.

It holds for fluids. It's possible to derive this relation as a classical example where you can use rules for differentiation of composite functions in thermodynamics.
Starting from the first principle
$$dU = - P dV + T dS \ ,$$
where the internal energy is written as a function of volume and entropy as independent variables, $U(V,S)$, it's possible to make the change of variables to write is as a function of volume and temperature,
$$\tilde{U}(V,T) = U(V, S(T,V)) \ ,$$
having introduced the tilde to emphasize that these functions have different independent variables, while representing the same physical quantity. Evaluating the differential
$$d U = d \tilde{U} = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial T} \bigg|_V dT + \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg|_T dV \ ,$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg|_T & = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg|_S + \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial S}\bigg|_V \dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\bigg|_T = \\
& = -P + T  \dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\bigg|_T \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
using the differential of the first principle to evaluate the partial derivatives of $U$ w.r.t. $V$ and $S$. The partial derivative remaining in the latter expression can be evaluated exploiting Schwartz theorem about mixed 2-order partial derivatives, or Maxwell relations for the Helmholtz free energy $dF = - P dV - S dT$, reading
$$\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\bigg|_T = \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial T}\bigg|_V \ .$$
Putting everything together, and using the definition of the heat capacity $C_V = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}_V$, we get the desired relation
$$d U = C_V dT + \left[ - P + T \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial T}\bigg|_V \right] dV$$
